# Java - Sorting in Comparator for use in Priority Queue

Tags: java, priority-queue, comparator

I am a bit confused on how to determine which way a priority queue sorts based on implementation in the comparator. Here, I want to sort based on descending `FScore`, so that means the lowest `FScore` would be at the top of the queue. I'm not sure if I did this correctly (I am using this for A * algorithm).

```
private class puzzleStateComparator implements Comparator<PuzzleState> {

    @Override
    public int compare(PuzzleState o1, PuzzleState o2) {
        //TODO

        int[] goalState = FastPuzzleSolver.this.initialState.getStateArray();

        int o1GScore = PuzzlePropertyUtility.numBlocksOutOfPlace(o1.getStateArray(), goalState);
        int o2GScore = PuzzlePropertyUtility.numBlocksOutOfPlace(o2.getStateArray(), goalState);

        int o1HScore = PuzzlePropertyUtility.calcManhattanDistanceSum(o1.getStateArray(), goalState);
        int o2HScore = PuzzlePropertyUtility.calcManhattanDistanceSum(o2.getStateArray(), goalState);

        int o1FScore = o1GScore + o1HScore;
        int o2FScore = o2GScore + o2HScore;

        return o1FScore - o2FScore;


    }
```

Comment: The easiest way is to try it.

Comment: @biziclop hmm, so there is no direct way to tell?I tried searching online, but answers are vague.

Comment: Of course there is but it depends on the priority queue implementation.

Answer (score 3):

One important thing, the correct way to compare two ints is this:

```
//ascending order
return Integer.compare( o1Fscore, o2Fscore );

//descending order
return Integer.compare( o2Fscore, o1Fscore );
```

Comparing ints with subtraction may lead to over/underflow issues.

If you're using `java.util.PriorityQueue`, then you definitely need the descending version, as the API doc says:

> The head of this queue is the **least** element with respect to the
>   specified ordering. If multiple elements are tied for least value, the
>   head is one of those elements -- ties are broken arbitrarily. The
>   queue retrieval operations poll, remove, peek, and element access the
>   element at the head of the queue.

As a complete aside: if `PuzzleState` is immutable (as it probably should be), it's worth calculating the G and H scores only once per state.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you calculate these values through PuzzlePropertyUtility but if you want a descending order you need to revert the return value as

```
 return o2FScore - o1FScore ;
```

Answer (score 0):

To sort your queue in reverse order, you should compare the second input with the first. In your case, it would be:

```
return o2FScore - o1FScore;
```